# "Send With DocuSign" URL Button Works In Sandbox But Not Production

Tags: api, docusignapi, apex

An APEX email error is received when trying to utilize the "Send With DocuSign" URL button on the contract object in Salesforce. This button was just created to meet the requirements to move from a JavaScript button. The button does not trigger an error in Sandbox, works as expected. But I can not replicate in production without getting the error shown below. Any idea on how to get this resolved?

```
Developer script exception from Franklin Madison Group : DocuSignAPICredentials : Please verify that you have been granted access to DocuSign, your account settings are correct and that you have responded to all activation emails.

Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization: 0053n000007GFbq/00D70000000Je65

Visualforce Page: /apex/dsfs__docusign_editenvelope

caused by: dsfs.UnauthorizedException: Please verify that you have been granted access to DocuSign, your account settings are correct and that you have responded to all activation emails.

Class.dsfs.DocuSignAPICredentials.getInstance: line 71, column 1
Class.dsfs.DocuSignAPICredentials.getInstance: line 56, column 1
Class.dsfs.AccountFeatures.getInstance: line 139, column 1
Class.dsfs.EnvelopeController.loadEnvelope: line 164, column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause
Common causes for the issue are listed below,

The DocuSign user associated with the Salesforce user sending the envelope is not active

The Salesforce user has not been added to the DocuSign users list in DocuSign Setup settings (in Salesforce)
You are attempting to use Salesforce Login Access on behalf of a user "not yet Authorized DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce (DAL)"
Note: If the user hasn't authorized already, please refer to Step 4 in this article

Solution
Before continuing, ensure that you are on the most recent version of DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce (DAL). If you are on an outdated version, some of these steps will be unavailable.

To resolve this error, you’ll need to verify both issues that cause this error has been addressed.

First, you’ll need to verify that this Salesforce user has been added to DocuSign.

To verify if a Salesforce user has been added properly:
Navigate to DocuSign Setup.
Select User Management, then select Add User.
Enter the name of the user in the Value box. When they appear in the search results, select the checkbox next to their name and select Continue.
Assign the appropriate permissions to the user and select Apply. If your package is up to date and a DocuSign user already exists for this user, the Salesforce user will be mapped to their existing DocuSign user.
Click Done to finish.

Second, verify that the DocuSign user associated with this Salesforce account is active.

To check if a user is active in DocuSign:

Navigate to the DocuSign web app and select Settings.
Navigate to Users and search for the user in question.
If the user is not active, select Actions > Resend Invitation to send the invite to the user again.

To activate a user:
The User will need to navigate to their email client and open the invitation email.
Click the link in the email to activate.
Create a password and security question.

Once the user is active, have the user attempt to send an envelope from Salesforce to confirm the issue is resolved.

Additional Troubleshooting
If the DAL Admin and all users are noticing the same error, try to disconnect and reconnect.

Steps to Disconnect [Note: Disconnecting accounts will remove the DocuSign Gen and DocuSign Negotiate permissions for the Salesforce users that were given access under the old connection. You have to re-add DocuSign users and permissions in your organization.]
Steps to Reconnect

If the Salesforce Administrator attempting to make this change is unable to access the DocuSign Setup object, ensure that they have the correct permission set assignment to access the object.

To view permission set assignments in Salesforce:

Navigate to Setup, select Users.
Navigate to the user in question and open their profile.
Navigate to Permission Set Assignments, if the DocuSign permissions are missing, edit the section and add DocuSign Administrator.

Note: If you are running both DocuSign Apps Launcher and legacy DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce, you will see duplicate permission sets with similar names. Add both to ensure correct permissions are applied to the user.

Retest to see if the user can access DocuSign Setup. If it’s still failing, follow the steps in this article to navigate to the DocuSign Troubleshooting page and select Delete DocuSign Credentials. You should then be able to navigate to DocuSign Setup and reestablish the connection between DocuSign and Salesforce.

Comment: Where is STEP 4 in this article?